# Pubnub Time to Live (TTL)

Tags: javascript, pubnub, ttl

How to I set a `TTL` on a published message to a channel?

I have been through the API docs on the website but I cannot seem to find any documentation, only a note for Pubnub APNs.

Answer (score 0):

## PubNub publish and storing messages

You can either store the message you publish or not store it (there is a [`store_in_history` parameter for `publish` API](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference#publish_args_1).

If the message is stored, its TTL (retention in storage) will be same as it is for all other messages published in your key set. This setting is in the Storage & Playback add-on for you keys in your [PubNub Admin Dashaboard](https://admin.pubnub.com)

[image]